# Add and remove a class on click using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, click

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/HTHnW/6/).

I am trying to add and remove a class on li elements that are clicked. It is a menu and when one clicks on each li item I want it to gain the class and all other li items have the class removed. So only one li item has the class at a time. This is how far I have got (see fiddle). I am not sure how to make the 'about-link' start with the class current, but then it is remove when one of the other li items are clicked on?

```
$('#about-link').addClass('current');
$('#menu li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Why not try something like this?

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnW/7/)

Comment: Brilliant.Could it get any better?

Answer (score 7):

you can try this along, it may help to give a shorter code on large function.

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $('li a.current').toggleClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The other li elements are not siblings of the a element.

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('current').parent().siblings().children().removeClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're applying your class to the `<a>` elements, which aren't siblings because they're each enclosed in an `<li>` element. You need to move up the tree to the parent `<li>` and find the ` elements in the siblings at that level.

```
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(){
$(this).addClass('current').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('current');
});
```

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnW/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:-

```
$('#about-link').addClass('current');
$('#menu li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#menu li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnW/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your Head section of the site:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu_box_list li').click(function() {
        $('.menu_box_list li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
$(function () {
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
   $("#btnClass").removeClass("btnDiv").addClass("btn");
   });
});
```

you can also use switchClass() method - it allows you to animate the transition of adding and removing classes at the same time.

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $("#btnClass").switchClass("btn", "btnReset", 1000, "easeInOutQuad");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var selector = '.classname';
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('classname');
    $(this).addClass('classname');
});
```