# How to remove class by click function using jquery

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have an image... what i want : when i click it, it should be scaled bigger and a class called "close" should be added to it. So, when i click it again, the image should be resized to its original size and i want to remove the class in the same time that it could be clicked again to grow...
I added successfully a class but i can not remove it.

THE HTML :

```
<div class="intro-img">
    <img src="uploads/images/2.jpg" alt="Sensuality 1" />
</div>
```

THE CSS :

```
.intro-img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 80%;
    max-width: 80%; 
    margin: 5% auto;
}
.intro-img img {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.intro-img img:hover {
    height: 105%;
    max-width: 105%;
}
```

THE SCRIPT :

```
$('.intro-img img').click(function(){
    $('.intro-img img').addClass( 'close');
    $('.intro-img').animate({'height':'100%','max-width':'100%','margin': '0 auto'}, 500, 'easeInCirc');
});
$('.intro-img .close').click(function(){
    $('.intro-img').animate({'margin': '5% auto','height':'80%','max-width':'80%'}, 500, 'easeInCirc');
    $(this).removeClass('close');
});
```

How to remove the "close" class by the second click ? What is wrong with my script ? 
(I read a post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520446/add-and-remove-a-class-on-click-using-jquery) but i could not use it to my case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script attempts to immediately attach a click handler to all elements matched by `.intro-img .close`, but there are no such elements in the document before you click the image. Therefore the click handler is not attached to anything.

A good solution is to use a [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) instead, e.g.

```
$('.intro-img').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $('.intro-img').animate(...);
    $(this).removeClass('close');
});
```

This handler attaches to `.intro-img` (which does exist from the beginning) and activates whenever any of its descendants that matches `.close` is clicked  -- which is exactly what you want.

**Update:** However, if you do the above then your first event handler will *also* trigger on clicking `.close`. To prevent that you could check if the `img` has `.close` inside the handler, or you could use the solution that follows.

Another good solution is to use a single handler for both toggling on and off, i.e. replacing both event handlers with this:

```
$('.intro-img img').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), isClose = $this.is(".close");
    if (!isClose) {
        $('.intro-img').animate(...);
    }
    else {
        $('.intro-img').animate(...);
    }
    $this.toggleClass("close");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... now, with your methode, when i click the image, it grows and it resize to original at the same time, you can see it here : http://photography.igorlaszlo.com/test2.html#sensuality

Comment: @IgorLaszlo: That's because the first event still fires. I updated the answer (I also added another approach in the meantime that doesn't have this problem).

Comment: #Jon Perfect, it works as it should ! Thanks, i voted for accepted answer !