# Remove previously added class by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a follow up question to this: [Add and remove a class on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520446/add-and-remove-a-class-on-click-using-jquery/19520629#19520629)

I'm able to add a class to a specific li element using this snipped by Jamie Taylor:

```
$('.team').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.team li#member').removeClass('more');
    $(this).addClass('more');
});
```

I'd like to remove the Class .more again, by clicking a toggle element inside the li-item.

My jQuery Snippet which doesn't work:

```
$('.toggle-x').click(function () {
    $('.team li#member').removeClass('more');
})
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: show us the html too..

Comment: You're not removing it from the element you clicked on, you're removing it from whatever `.team li#member` matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because when you click on an element X inside the `<li />` the element fires the `click` event, and if you don't use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) the `<li />` will also fire the `click` event and the class will be added again.

Try this:

```
$('.toggle-x').click(function (e) {
    $('.team li#member').removeClass('more');
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

It should work if that's your problem.

Comment: Wow this was fast. This one works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, it will remove the class form only one element with id `member`. If you want to remove the class from all the `li` elements, use like this,

```
$('.team li.more').removeClass('more');
```

Comment: I tried this before, didn‘t help. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    $(".innerLiContent").click(function(){
       $(this).parentsUntil( "li" ).removeClass('more');
    });
```

Comment: I tried it, doesn‘t seem to work. But thanks anyway.