# add and remove class on same button or element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm looking for a way to add and remove class on the same button. So far this is my work in progress. The concept is when I click on the menu button it shows the menu. When I tap on the menu button again. The menu hides

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function(e){
      $('.portfolio-contact-form-wrap').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('button.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function(e){
      $(this).toggleClass('show');
    });` try this *on same button?*

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking... At least, provide relevant HTML markup and better describe expected behaviour

Comment: Seriously, Please Use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+toggle+class+on+element).....

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19520446/5620297

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `.toggleClass()` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function(e){
      $('.portfolio-contact-form-wrap').toggleClass('show');
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov3gmcqv/) example

---

**toggleClass**

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.
>
> This method takes one or more class names as its parameter. In the first version, if an element in the matched set of elements already has the class, then it is removed; if an element does not have the class, then it is added.

For more information about this function check [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should use $(this) and toggleClass

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function(e){
      $(this).toggleClass('show');
    });
});
```

which will add the class back to the specific element that was clicked.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function(e){
     $('.portfolio-contact-form-wrap').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/tz94mpkj/2/)

```
$('.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.portfolio-contact-form-wrap').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Try this way

Comment: OP doesn't want to toggle class on clicked element :)  EDIT: oops looks like quite confusing sentence indeed: `I'm looking for a way to add and remove class on the same button` and regarding OP's posted code

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually I wanted to clarify it but he didnt respond so i assumed that the clicked button but then i changed my answer hoping this is what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.add()` method with `.toggleClass()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.portfolio-contact-form-wrap').add(this).toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.portfolio-contact-form-wrap {
  color:blue;
}
.show {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle-portfolio">Button</button>
<div class="portfolio-contact-form-wrap">
  <h1>contact form</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggleClass('show')
It will add the class on one click and remove the class on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('button.toggle-portfolio').on('click', function (e) {
            $('.portfolio-contact-form-wrap').toggleClass('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: for the `nth time` :)