# Showing 'active' tab on navigation

Tags: html, css, class, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I'm trying to show the `active` tag on my nav bar. It shows on all tabs EXCEPT one with a drop-down. I can't figure out why its not calling the class on this particular button. I'm obviously placing it in the wrong place. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!

Code: (The first one is CORRECT - ie - **index.php** is currently active. Where do I place the code (`class="active"`) to make the next button (WHAT WE DO) the active tab when clicked?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i>HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" role="presentation"> 
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">WHAT WE DO <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="whatwedo_qualitative.php">QUALITATIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="whatwedo_quantitative.php">QUANTITATIVE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="wherewework.php">WHERE WE WORK</a></li>
    <li> <a href="ourclients.php">OUR CLIENTS </a></li>
    <li> <a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>  
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a javascript code to add/remove active class to the a link pressed.. something like this:

```js
$("a").click(function() {  
  //remove all active class from a elements
  $(this).addClass("active");      //add the class to the clicked element
});
```

a similar functionality is here: [Add and remove a class on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520446/add-and-remove-a-class-on-click-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to check the URL. (In my demo I set it to a specific URL) Then, add a class to the `li` parent.

```js
var page = 'whatwedo_qualitative.php';

var a = $('[href="' + page + '"]');
$('.dropdown').has(a).addClass('active');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i>HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" role="presentation"> 
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">WHAT WE DO <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="whatwedo_qualitative.php">QUALITATIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="whatwedo_quantitative.php">QUANTITATIVE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="wherewework.php">WHERE WE WORK</a></li>
    <li> <a href="ourclients.php">OUR CLIENTS </a></li>
    <li> <a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>  
  </ul>
</nav>
```