# How can I define a set of CSS rules that can be added as class using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the `addClass` function to add class via JavaScript, but I just can't add the class. Is there a special way to define a class that will be added to an element `onclick`?
This is what I have tried:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.sb-input');
var image = document.querySelector('.sb-label img');
image.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (classie.has(input, 'open'))
    classie.remove(input, 'open')
  else
    classie.add(input, 'open');
  console.log('I am back')
});
```

```css
.search-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sb-label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #32ab32;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sb-label img {
  display: block;
  z-index: 30;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sb-input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: left 0.7s;
  z-index: 5;
}
.sb-input .open {
  z-index: 90;
}
.sb-input .open {
  width: 100%;
  transition: left 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <form>
    <label class="sb-label" id="sb-label">
      <img src="search-icon01.png" width="35px" height="35px">
    </label>
    <input type="search" class="sb-input" id="sb-input" placeholder="Enter Search Word">
  </form>
</div>
```

I added a callback and I got a message on my console, indicating that the function is ok, and when I did this, it works:

```
var input = document.querySelector('.sb-input');
var image = document.querySelector('.sb-label img');
image.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.style.zIndex = 90;
  input.style.width = '100%';
  console.log('I did it')
});
```

Apparently the problem is with my stylesheet. Could somebody please help me to correct this anomaly?

Comment: you can use jquery's add class method https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19520629/4361743

Comment: its same result, it seems the problem is with my css, on defining thee open class

Comment: You are not adding css class in your description above. Can you please post whole code above, or create a fiddle for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious where did you get `classie` from? Use `classList`, I think `classie` is too classy for us lowly developers:P

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    .search-bar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      right: 60px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .sb-label {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      display: block;
      width: 50px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #32ab32;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .sb-label img {
      display: block;
      z-index: 30;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .sb-input {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 40px;
      border: none;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transition: left 0.7s;
      z-index: 5;
    }
    .sb-input .open {
      z-index: 90;
    }
    .sb-input .open {
      width: 100%;
      transition: left 0.7s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <form>
      <label class="sb-label" id="sb-label">
        <img src="search-icon01.png" width="35px" height="35px">
      </label>
      <input type="search" class="sb-input" id="sb-input" placeholder="Enter Search Word">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    var input = document.querySelector('.sb-input');
    var image = document.querySelector('.sb-label img');
    image.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (input.classList.contains('open')) {
        input.classList.remove('open');
      } else {
        input.classList.add('open');
        console.log('i am back')
      }

    });
    var input = document.querySelector('.sb-input');
    var image = document.querySelector('.sb-label img');
    image.addEventListener('click', function() {
      input.style.zIndex = 90;
      input.style.width = '100%';
      console.log('did i do it')
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it seems to work here, but i copied your javascript code to my editor, but it didnt work.

Comment: Is there more on your page than this Snippet? Because the code is simple and straight forward.

Comment: Don't copy the first code, copy the actual Snippet.

Comment: thougth i have a header that contain a navigation list on the left, but that wouldn't interfer with the javascript na

Comment: Updated copy the whole thing on a blank page, then start adding anything **not** on the page gradually.

Comment: thanks, your reputation is pretty robust, how did you garner this much?

Comment: You are very welcome. Answering questions I know the answer to, or I think I could solve if I work on it. It became a daily habit I guess. The only real advantage I see in having a score of 7000+ is I don't get harassed anymore. So I assume you got things working, what was the problem?

Comment: the problem was actually with my style sheet. This what i wrote: .sb-input .open{}, there was a space between the open class and the sb-input class, I thought it should be like this .sb-input.open {} . But that kind of declaration, looks new to me, i thought there is always spaces to show descendant relationships

Comment: You thought correctly, a space between is a descendant selector: `.sb-input .open {}` and this: `.sb-input.open {}` is just some element with two classes.

Comment: Thank you very much, with two classes, that makes better sense.