# How to set jquery addClass/removeClass

Tags: jquery

I have a button-group radio button input. When the form opens both buttons are set to default. If the user clicks yes it turns green. If the user toggles to no the button turn red and the green button should go back to default. How do I toggle a button back to default after it add class then remove class? jQuery?

Comment: Please add what have you done to accomplish this requirement

Comment: Please show us some code and format your question properly and clearly. Also, make sure to first search on SO before posting a question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add and remove a class on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520446/add-and-remove-a-class-on-click-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to the above question:

```
$("div.question").find(':radio').click(function () {
        var isValid = $(this).hasClass('True');
        var divAlert = $(this).parents('.question').find('div.alert_text');
        debugger
        if (!isValid) {
            divAlert.show();
            if (divAlert.show()) {
                $(this).parents('.btn').addClass('btn-danger');
                $(this).parents('.btn').removeClass('btn-default');
                $(this).parents('.btn').removeClass('btn-success');
                //$(this).addClass(parents('.btn').siblings('.btn').removeClass('.btn');
            } 
        }
        else {
            divAlert.hide();
            if (divAlert.hide()) {
                $(this).parents('.btn').addClass('btn-success');
                $(this).parents('.btn').removeClass('btn-default');
                $(this).parents('.btn').removeClass('btn-danger');
            }

        }

        // Enable-Disable Next Button
        if ($(":radio:checked.True").length == @Model.Count()) {
            $("#next").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("k-state-disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#next").prop("checked", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
        }
    })
});
```