# Call class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have little problems with JavaScript onClick function.
I need function that will get class, for example .modal. It's look like this right now

```
<div class="modal" onclick="modalFix()">
<p>here is some text</p>
</div>
```

And there is script that works, but i must delete  onclick="modalFix()"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function modalFix(){
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    };
</script>
```

How to rewrite that same JavaScript function so i can call div class from it?

Comment: $('.modal').removeAttr('onclick')

Comment: Sorry i'm not good with JavaScript. That text must replace function modalFix(){ ?

Comment: you have used jQuery also don't forget that.

Comment: What do you mean "call div class from it"? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @RadeIlijev Remove the attribute from HTML and try `$('.modal').on('click', function() { ... })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add and remove a class on click using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520446/add-and-remove-a-class-on-click-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.model').click(function() {
        $("body").addClass("modal-open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry still nothing